# Javascript form validation. How to use external .js validation script

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with Javascript form validation. I don't know how to use the external .js script with validation rules and insert them into a html file and get them working.

I have linked the script in the head section like this:

This is what's in the .js validation script

```
  function IsValid4DigitZip( str ) 
    if (str+"" == "undefined" || str+"" == "null" || str+"" == "")  
        return false;

    var isValid = true;

    str += "";

   if (IsBlank(str) || (str.length != 4) || !IsInt(str, false))
        isValid = false;

   return isValid;
}
```

I tried inserting it into the  section as follows

```
    function IsValid4DigitZip(document.orderbooks.Postcode) {

    if (document.orderbooks.Postcode.value+"" == "undefined" || document.orderbooks.Postcode.value+"" == "null" || document.orderbooks.Postcode.value+"" == "") 
        alert("Invalid Postcode !") 
        return false;

    var isValid = true;

    document.orderbooks.Postcode += "";


   if (IsBlank(document.orderbooks.Postcode) || (document.orderbooks.Postcodestr.length != 4) || !IsInt(document.orderbooks.Postcode, false))
        alert("Invalid Postcode!") 
        isValid = false;

   return isValid;
}
```

orderbooks is my form name in my html and Postcode is the name attribute I want to validate using javascript..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do not modify the existing function - you need to pass your data into it and capture the return to further process it. [Here is some basic reading to do](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp). You also mention your HTML but it doesn't seem to be added to the question which makes it only more difficult to answer.

Comment: I don't get it :( Sorry I am new to this. Can you show me and example?  How do I pass the data and capture it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the zip code validation function, you just have to call it for form data.

```
if ( IsValid4DigitZip(document.orderbooks.Postcode.value) ) {
  // Zip code is valid
} else {
  // Zip code is invalid
}
```

Comment: But wait! There is more! `orderbooks is my form name in my html and Postcode is the name attribute` is the part that made me realize how much broader this "question" is and how answering it is impossible without explaining a large chunk of JS and HTML.

Comment: I just uploaded my html can you take a look and get back to me?

Comment: Don't see any html